# ind the image of the semicircle $z(t) = 2 e^{it}$, $0\leq t \leq \pi$ under the complex mapping $w = z^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading Dennis Zill complex analysis book where I am having difficulty in understanding following example.

**Example:** Find the image of the semicircle $z(t) = 2 e^{it}$, $0\leq t \leq \pi$ under the complex mapping $w = z^2$.

**Solution:** Let $C$ denote the semicircle and let $C_1$ denote its image under $f(z) = z^2$. Then image curve $C_1$: $w(t) = f(z(t)) = (2e^{it})^2 = 4e^{2it}$, $0 ≤ t ≤ π$.

**If we set $t = \frac{1}{2} s$ above, then we obtain a new
parametrization of $C_1$: $W(s) = 4e^{is}$, $0 ≤ s ≤ 2π$. Therefore, the image $C_1$ is the circle $|w| = 4$.**

The lines written in black fonts are my confusion. How can we choose $t = \frac{1}{2} s$? How could $C_1$: $w(t) = 4e^{2it}$, $0 ≤ t ≤ π$ and $W(s) = 4e^{is}$, $0 ≤ s ≤ 2π$ are same when the ranges of $t$ and $s$ are different?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We choose $t = \frac12s$ so that $W(s)$ is in the form $W(s) = k e^{is}$, which is something that is very familiar and we can handle very well.

The range for $s$ comes directly from the range of $t$:

$$0 \le t \le \pi$$

$$0 \le \frac12s \le \pi$$

$$2 \cdot 0 \le 2 \cdot \frac12s \le 2 \cdot \pi$$

$$0 \le s \le 2 \pi$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clearing my doubt.